# How do I install Flask using PyCharm

Tags: flask, pycharm

How do I install Flask in PyCharm?

Comment: I prefer sublime.. And I prefer to install command line using `pip install flask`

Answer (score 11):

In pycharm, Go to:
File-->Settings-->Project:project_name-->Project Interpreter.

Click on the **+** sign **search** for Flask. Choose it and click on **Install package**

Alternative approach:
add requirements.txt to the root of your project. in it add the following line:

```
Flask==0.10.1
```

Note: keep an eye out for the version.

After you do that pycharm will prompt you to install the requirements, Just click on install requirements and if all is good you are good to go.